# redirect to action asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect  to an action afer the execution of create method

**so the create method returns this:**

```
  return Json(new 
             {
                 Data = base.RenderView("_Forme ", model),
                 Message = (string)TempData[TEMP_DATA_MESSAGE_KEY],
                 Result = (AjaxResultType)TempData[TEMP_DATA_CODE_KEY]

             }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

**Layout page:**

```
      <div> @Html.Partial("_Forme") </div>
         @if (@Model.nouveau==false)
            {
               <div> @Html.Partial("_Onglet") </div>
                <div> @Html.Partial("_Details") </div>
            }
```

**In the View: _Forme.cshtml **

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Uneform")"

     @if (Model.nouveau==true)
         { Create}
        {  Update }
 </a>
```

I want to be able to refrech the layout page and display all the partial views.
I already try redirect to action using javascript didn't work,any help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh only some part of the layout page, wrap that in a container div and make an ajax call to get the new markup for this area

```
<div id="updatable">
@if (@Model.nouveau==false)
{
  <div> @Html.Partial("_Onglet") </div>
  <div> @Html.Partial("_Details") </div>
}
</div>
```

and in your ajax call's `success` event, you may use the `$.load` method

```
$("#updatable").load("/Home/GetUpdatedHeader");
```

Assuming `GetUpdatedHeader` action method return a partial view which has the other 2 partials in it.

---

If you simply want to reload the same page, you can do this in javascript.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

You can do this is in your ajax call's `success` event.

If you want to redirect to another action/page

```
window.location.href ="/Home/Index"; //Replace this value with your url
```

You may also send the url for your new page in the json response(You can use the UrlHelper to build the urls) and use that for the redirect.

Comment: I want to reload the layout page only if(model.nouveau==false)

Comment: Then you need to use ajax to update it. See the updated answer

Comment: ok so how can i pass a parameter to GetUpdatedHeader method ?

Comment: you can add a querystring value or pass an object. load method can have a second param where you can pass params

Comment: this is actually helpfull thank you, I have one more question is it possible to call ajax function inside if statement  in the view?

Comment: yes. you need to put it in script blocks. But remember your view code gets executed in server and your js variable values might be available at that time.

Comment: it didn't work because the layout view that calls the ajax function doesn't get called on the create method

Comment: you have to make the call (to update part of your page) in the success event of the ajax call you are making for the create.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: In the success event of the ajax call for your create action, `success:function(){ $("#updatable").load("/Home/GetUpdatedHeader"); });`

Comment: @if (Model.nouveau == false)
{
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',

                success: function () {
                    
                    load("/Uneform/Index",@Model.Id);
                }
            });

    });
    </script>
}

Comment: and what is not working ? Check your browser console for errors

Comment: the thing is this code will never be executed because it is on the layout page and in the create method I render only the partialView _Forme

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing how you are doing your create. With the current code you provided, It is hard to understand. Please make sure to post relevant information when you post a question.